# On view call other controllers http request getting triggered automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have a file "controller.js" Which has homeController and sectionController defined.

in route.js

```
 when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'view/main/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController',
                access: {
                        requiredLogin: false
                        }

            }).
            when('/section/:menu', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/main/section.html',
                    controller: 'sectionController',
                    access: {
                            requiredLogin: false
                            }

                })
```

but when call to /section/ is made. I could still see $http request defined in homeController being made. Can anybody please tell me the reason and how to tackle this. A proper binding of controllers to the views.

Comment: are you instantiating homeController in your html?  Like ng-controller="homeController"?

Comment: no, I am not instantiating homeController in my html.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be in your routing, so post your section.html, and your controller code.  Relevant bits at least.  A plunker would be helpful as well.

Comment: Problem is resolved. My bad there was an instantiating in footer section. Thanks tpie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the controller is not being instantiating in your html with ng-controller.

Comment: Thanks issue resolved. Apart from this, there was a use of $interval. In each cycle a call was made. When a change in route occurred $interval was active. Found an explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420817/angularjs-interval-being-called-multiple-times  now the issue is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this, there was a use of $interval. In each cycle, a call was made. When a change in route occurred $interval was not destroyed and remain active. Found an explanation at [angularjs $interval being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420817/angularjs-interval-being-called-multiple-times) now the issue is resolved.